# Rounding in binary

Tags: proof-verification, binary

If I have the number $x$ in binary:

$x=.1101001$

Would the following be correct, when rounding to...

Three decimal places: $x=.111$

Four decimal places: $x=.1101$

Five decimal places: $x=.11010$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would be correct.  Because each position in binary is half the previous you can just chop off the unwanted bits and increment by $1$ if the first bit you discarded is a $1$.  That works perfectly if you round up on exactly half.  Otherwise you have to figure out what to do if you are chopping off a $1$ with nothing at all behind it.